# Priority of DNS resolution

Tags: dns, subdomain, tld

As a Scott, I'm curious what happens on the internet if there's website at the "s" domain with ".co.tt" TLD, and another one at "co" domain with ".tt" TLD and "s" subdomain.

Which site would visitors see at http://s.co.tt?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

DNS is a database. The domain name is the key to a place in this database. The name `s.co.tt` can only lead to one place, and so the case you're imagining cannot exist (or, differently put, the two cases you imagine to be different are actually exactly the same).